# How can I change the color of the my ImageView in Swift?

Tags: swift

I can't seem to be able to change the color of the icon :
here i add the icon :

```
   iconImg = UIImage(systemName: iconName)!.withTintColor(UIColor(named: "blue")!, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
            imageView.image = iconImg
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 40))
            view.addSubview(imageView)
```

and here i try to change the color once input is selected:

```
 @objc func active(textField: UITextField) {
        animateLine(show: true)
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            iconImg.withTintColor(UIColor(named: "red")!, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't change UIImage, change UIImageView tint color:

```
imageView.tintColor = .red
```

Comment: so you can only set one time the UIimage tint color ?

Comment: You can do it multiple times, whenever you want